# Cannot assign to immutable expression of type after forced downcast

Tags: swift

Here is the code:

```
protocol A {
    var a: Double { get set }
}

struct B: A {
    var a: Double = 1
    var b: Double = 2
}

class C {

    var b: A = B()

    func setValue(_ value: Double) {
        b.a = value
        (b as! B).b = 1 // got an error
    }

}
```

How can I set the `b.b` value from `setValue`? When I'm trying to set it, I've got an compilation error:

> Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Double'

My B is a `struct`, so I can't use `protocol A: class {`

Comment: `(b as! B)` expression returns immutable value. If you for example change `struct B` to `class B` everything will work.

Comment: If you have a need to force-cast `b` to a `B`, then why bother declaring `b` as an `A`? Simply change `var b: A = B()` to `var b = B()`.

Comment: @rmaddy this is very simplified example. Of course if I set it to B everything will work, but I need it to be A. B isn't the only one struct in project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be compiler  glitch try this , you may also make struct B a class to overwrite the value

```
 var rr =  (b as! B)

 rr.b = 1.0
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to change my var b value, so then I need to call b = rr after. This works, but looks a little bit weird, isn't it? Creating struct copy just to change one value.

Comment: if your intend  is to overwrite , then class approach is the best

Comment: @GuessWho well, by mutating struct property, you creating struct copy under the hood, so it's not that weird. In fact, changing property of mutable struct was source of common errors in pre-swift days.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.